# Are the numbers 1, 0, -1 necessarily in every field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Do the numbers 1, 0, and -1 belong to every field? To me, this seems a fairly obvious conclusion of the field axioms, though I haven't seen it stated like so in any textbooks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" numbers? Are you claiming some kind of uniqueness?

Comment: Yes, necessarily they are in every field. Remember that $0$ and $1$ are in every field by definition and that $-1$ is, by definition, the only number $x$ in the field such that $1+x=0$. This number $x$ also is in every field by definition. It can happen that $-1=1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$0$ is in $F$, because $F$ is a group w.r.t. addition, it must have an identity element, we *denote* it as $0$.

$1$ is in $F$, because $F\backslash\{0\}$ is a group w.r.t. multiplication, it must have an identity element, we *denote* it as $1$.

$-1$ is in $F$, since $-1$ is the additive inverse of $1$ in the group $F$.

However, those elements can be the same, e.g. $-1=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: +1 For the last line: `those elements can be the same`!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes and no.

Yes, every field has the **elements** $-1,0,1$. But, they are not necessarily the (real) numbers $-1,0,1$, they are just the elements given by the axioms. $1$ in the field doesn't mean the real number $1$.

Also, note that if your field has characteristic $2$, we have $-1=1$, so the three elements you listed are actually two.

**Added**: If the field has zero characteristic, then you can actually embed $\mathbb Z$ into the field. This, would allow us to view $-1, 0, 1$ as the **integers** $-1,0,1$, but we need to be very careful. What happens in this case, is that the field $k$ has a subring which is the same (i.e. isomorphic) as $\mathbb Z$. And note that in this case, even if we can identify a part of $k$ as "being" $\mathbb Z$, it is often the case that we cannot view all the elements in $k$ as "numbers".

In finite characteristic you can only embed a factor of $\mathbb Z$ in the field, it would be wrong to think about $1$ as being a real number. The main issue is that in this case we have

$$1+1+1+....+1=0$$

Comment: I really don't see how the answer can be *no* or how you've explained it can be *no*.

Comment: I can, @GitGud: N.S. explained that *if* the OP meant the real numbers $\;-1,0,1\;$ , which would be a rather reasonable assumption by the question's character, then the answer is no. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah, thanks. I was missing on that interpretation of the question.

Comment: @GitGud It all depends what you understand by numbers. It would be wrong to understand that the elements $-1,0,1$ of the field are the real numbers $-1,0,1$. Just look at the field $\mathbb Z /2 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @N.S. Yes, as I explained above, it just never crossed my mind to look at $-1, 0$ and $1$ as real numbers. I got it now.

Comment: And one more comment, if the field has zero characteristic, then $\mathbb Z$ can be embedded in the field and then you can see think about $-1,0,1$ as the real numbers $-1,0,1$ (actually that is not correct, you can only think of them as the INTEGERS $-1,0,1$), but only if you are careful. In finite characteristic, you can only embed a factor $\mathbb Z/ p \mathbb Z$, so it is not really correct to think about 1 as being the real number 1.

Answer (score 1):

All the integers are, although they might coincide.  Start with the multiplicative identity, and add it to copies of itself.  Or start with its additive inverse.

Comment: Your first four words, with the usual mathematical meaning, are completely false. Check this.

Comment: @DonAntonio Can you explain why this is false?

Comment: @KennySong Do you know about finite fields?

Comment: I think he means every field admits a homomorphic image of Z by mapping $1$ to $1$ and extending by linearity. By coinciding he means the quotient. It's poorly written.

Comment: @GitGud I don't know enough to understand TBrendle's comment, but are you saying that all the (infinite) integers cannot fit inside a finite field? Then, to clarify, are all the integers not implicitly inside $\mathbb{Z}_2$ somehow?

Comment: @KennySong Not exactly. You shouldn't think of $0$ and $1$ in $\Bbb Z_2$ as integers. Rather they are elements of a certain field which we call $\Bbb Z_2$ and we **denote** them by $0$ and $1$ for convenience, but they **are not** integers.

Answer (score 1):

If you require $1,0$ and $-1$ to be *unique*, then no. For the Boolean numbers $\mathbb{F}_2$ contain only $(0,1)$ where $1$ is self inverse, ie $1+1=0$. But if $1$ is not self inverse (with respect to addition in your field) then the 3 numbers will be distinct.

There's also the trivial example of the field with one element, but I don't think that's what your looking for.